# How to eager load relationships at the time i query the parent model using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a Adress table and a Kontokorrent table. I need to return them and show on google maps.

this is my controller:

```
$addresses = Address::whereHas('kontokorrent', function($query) {
            $query->ktoArt('D')->mandant(1)->aktiv();
        });

        //Conditional                
        if(!! Auth::user()->activeAddress) {
            $addresses->where('Aktiv', '<>', 0); 
        }


         $addressesFormated = $addresses->get()->map(function($item, $key) {
             return [
                  'addresse' => $item->Adresse,
                  'kto' => $item->kontokorrent->Kto,
                  'name' => $item->Name1,
                  'anschrift' => ['strasse' => $item->LieferStrasse, 'plz' => $item->LieferPLZ, 'ort' => $item->LieferOrt, 'land' => $item->LieferLand],
                  'telefon' => $item->Telefon,
                  'email' => $item->Email,
                  'coords' => ["lat" => $item->USER_CCgeoLatitude, "lng" => $item->USER_CCgeoLongitude],
                  'umsatz' => number_format(Umsatz::year($item->kontokorrent->Kto, date('Y')),2),
                  'vorjahresUmsatz' => number_format(Umsatz::year($item->kontokorrent->Kto, date('Y')-1),2),
                  'letzteBestellung' => \Carbon\Carbon::parse($item->kontokorrent->LetzterUmsatz)->toDateString()           
             ];
         });
 dd($addressesFormated);
```

i'm iterating through the collection and passes each value as `key=>value`.
This is working but is very slow. I need >30sec when i'm interating over 10k rows.

maybe i should use the eager loading to increase the performence.

unfortunely i'm getting no relation

> relations: array:1 [
>           "kontokorrent" => null
>         ]

in array when i try this in my controller:

```
$addresses = $addresses->with('kontokorrent:Kto')->take(10)->get(['Name1', 'LieferStrasse', 'LieferLand', 'LieferOrt', 'LieferPLZ', 'Telefon', 'EMail', 'USER_CCgeoLatitude', 'USER_CCgeoLongitude']);

        dd($addresses);
```

i have also tried to put the `Kto` into the `->get()` function. But i get an error.

Comment: What are the foreign key columns between `address` and `kontokorrent`?

Comment: Adresse in address class and Adresse in kontokorrent class. When i test the relationsship with this: `$addresses = $addresses->with('kontokorrent')->first();` I get everthing correct. The problem is i would like to geht some specific columns.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the required foreign key column:

```
$addresses->with('kontokorrent:Adresse,Kto')
```

Comment: thank you this is working until 2100 queries: `Tried to bind parameter number 2101. SQL Server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters.`

Comment: You are loading too many `Kontokorrent` items. See https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/410.

Comment: is there a way to chunk this big data set ?

Comment: Are you getting this error with `$addresses->with('kontokorrent:kontokorrent:Adresse,Kto')->take(10)->get(...)`?

Comment: i get an error with this: `$addresses->with('kontokorrent:Adresse,Kto')->get();`

Comment: I guess you'll have to get the addresses without eager loading first. Then use something like `$addresses->chunk($x)->each->load('kontokorrent:Adresse,Kto')` (untested).

Comment: Thank you. I will try to chunk the data. Maybe there is a better solution to pass an array of data to google maps api (javascript).